# Program does not rise predefined ZeroDivisionError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a simple BMI calculator program and I wish it to take users back to the input field if they try zero division. i defined what output should be at that situation but it still prints out ZeroDivisionError

```
def bmi_calculator():
    user_height = float(input('Enter your height in cm: '))  # user height in cm
    user_weight = float(input('Enter your weight in kg: '))  # user weight in kb
    bmi = user_weight / (user_height / 100) ** 2  # BMI formula
    while user_height <= 0 or user_weight <= 0:
        try:
            print("your weight or height can't be below or equal 0 \n enter your credentials again... ")
            user_height = float(input('Enter your height in cm: '))
            user_weight = float(input('Enter your weight in kg: '))
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print("You can't divide by 0")
            user_height = float(input('Enter your height in cm: '))  # user height in cm
            user_weight = float(input('Enter your weight in kg: '))  # user weight in kb
    print(f'Your BMI is: {bmi}')

print(bmi_calculator())
```

Comment: You have no division inside the `try`.

Comment: Why not just do `if user_height == 0:`?

Comment: To run the zerodivision error exception you need to divide something by zero in the `try` statement so I think you need to put the `bmi` variable inside `try` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already specified the problem in your code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69952035/program-does-not-rise-predefined-zerodivisionerror/69952208#comment123654637_69952035), additionly:-

You are asking for the input from the user every time uneccesarily here's a short answer:

```
def bmi_calculator():
    while True:
        try:
            error="your weight or height can't be below or equal 0"
            height = float(input('Enter your height in cm: '))
            weight = float(input('Enter your weight: '))
            bmi=weight / (height / 100) ** 2
            if weight==0:
                print(error)
                continue
            print(f'Your BMI is {bmi}')
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print(error)
bmi_calculator()
```

**Note:-** The BMI can be displayed in negative number which isn't correct I leave it to tackle that exception upon you. If you aren't able to solve that you can comment below this answer and I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: ZeroDivisionError is working but with the code you provided if i try to enter positive height and zero weight it prints out height * 0.

Comment: @LukaMorchiladze thanks for pointing that out! I have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

For the ZeroDivisionError exception to be caught, put the line of code for the division *inside* the `try` block.
Then, if the specified exception occurs, the `except` statement comes into action and prints,
`You can't divide by 0`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you first make the division then start the `while` loop. This should be something like this:

```
def bmi_calculator():
    user_height = float(input('Enter your height in cm: '))  # user height in cm
    user_weight = float(input('Enter your weight in kg: '))  # user weight in kb

    while user_height <= 0 or user_weight <= 0:
        print("your weight or height can't be below or equal 0 \n enter your credentials again... ")
        user_height = float(input('Enter your height in cm: '))
        user_weight = float(input('Enter your weight in kg: '))

    bmi = user_weight / (user_height / 100) ** 2  # BMI formula
    print(f'Your BMI is: {bmi}')

bmi_calculator()
```

After all, I recommended using `if` statement in the `while` loop for more clarification.